# Makefile: create prerequisite from a list

Tags: make

The usual way to create a 1:1 dependency in Makefiles is by using `%`, e.g.

```
%o:%cc
```

Imagine I have 50 `.cc` files and I am interested in only 3 of them. I have constructed a list of their basenames:

```
CC_BASENAMES := Source15 Source32 Source41
```

How can I create a prerequisite for an `.o` file by iterating over the items in `$(CC_BASENAMES)`. The effect should be equivalent to:

```
Source15.o: Source15.cc

Source32.o: Source32.cc

Source41.o: Source41.cc
```

Comment: How is this a unix or linux question? Shouldn't it be on stackoverflow or some programming site?

Comment: This is a Unix question because `make` is a Unix tool.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but there are several simple ways for manipulating strings.

For example, you can add the suffix `.o` to each of your basenames with `OBJS = $(addsuffix .o,$(CC_BASENAMES))`.

You can convert one suffix to another, for example `$(OBJS:.o=.cc)`.
So perhaps what you want is a Makefile such as

```
CC_BASENAMES := Source15 Source32 Source41
OBJS = $(addsuffix .o,$(CC_BASENAMES))
SRCS = $(OBJS:.o=.cc)

fred.o: $(SRCS)
        cc $(SRCS) -o fred.o
```

Or more usually you would define SRCS first and derive OBJS from it.

---

If you want a dependency rule to apply to just some targets, you can use *targets: target-pattern: prereq-patterns* ie

```
$(OBJS): %.o: %.cc
```

See [gnu make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage).

Comment: That is not an answer to the question. I clarified the question.

Comment: Do you mean something like `$(OBJS): $(@:.o=.cc)`

Comment: No. What you wrote means that all object files depend on all source files. I want 1:1 dependencies.

Comment: Do you mean then `$(OBJS): %.o: %.cc`

Comment: The cc files come from the list

Comment: Did you check the addition to my answer? OBJS does indeed come from your list.

Answer (score 2):

Having a general build rule (like `%o:%cc`) doesn't mean that `make` will have to go though all 50 source files every time. What you need to do is specify a the output you want, and let `make` apply the rule to build it for you. E.g. you could run

```
$ make Source15.o Source32.o Source41.o
```

on the command line, or create a specific target in your makefile

```
my_build: Source15.o Source32.o Source41.o
```

and then ask `make` to build that target:

```
$ make my_build
```